# Handle 404 not found response with Ember and Ember-CLI-Mirage

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm trying to return different responses in Ember-CLI-Mirage depending on if a record is in the (fake) database. But I keep getting an adapter error when I return a response without a valid JSONAPI response even if I return a 404 response code.

```
this.get('/users/:id', (db, request) => {
  let user = db.users.find(request.params.id);
  if (user) {
    return jsonapi.serializeOne(user); // works
  } else {
    return new Mirage.Response(404, null, null);
  }
});
```

This is the route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  errorRedirectTo: 'users',
  model: function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('user');
  }
});
```

Error message:

```
Error while processing route: user Adapter operation failed Error: Adapter operation failed
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26266:21)
    at Error.ember$data$lib$adapters$errors$$AdapterError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:126403:50)
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.handleResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:128081:16)
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.ajax.Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:128177:33)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3350:30)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3462:7)
    at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9518:14)
    at Object.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9920:8)
    at Object._readyStateChange (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:69915:14)
```

Comment: You'll have to `.catch` in your route anyway, right? Just do that and handle the error.

It may involve having the header and `errors` key, something like 

`return new Mirage.Response(404, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, {errors: []});`

but even that was erroring for me.

Comment: Thanks @SamSelikoff, I tried using catch and setting the response type but i still get the same error. I'm having a hard time finding an authoritative source on what the correct JSONAPI response should be, JSONAPI.org simply states that the response code 404 should be used if any of the requested resources cannot be found - I belive that returning a description of the error (in the response body) is optional.